# Regex to extract SSIS formulas in Notepad++

Tags: regex, ssis, notepad++, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a long list of formulas in Microsoft SSIS that I have to translate into SQL queries. All the formulas of my list are basically made with the following rules:

- `PART_1 ? PART_2 : PART_3` means if PART_1 (test) is true then PART_2, if false then PART_3
- `&&` means AND (for different conditions in PART_1 (test)

My target is to extract in Notepad++ the PART_1, PART_2 and PART_3 **from most external expressions**, like the following examples:

#### Case I

Expression: `A>0 ? B : C`

- PART_1 (test) => `A>0`
- PART_2 (if true) => `B`
- PART_3 (if false) => `C`

#### Case II

Expression: `A>0 && (A>10 ? A : -A) ? B : C`

- PART_1 (test) => `A>0 && (A>10 ? A : -A)`
- PART_2 (if true) => `B`
- PART_3 (if false) => `C`

#### Case III

Expression: `A>0 ? B : (C>14 ? A*14 : -4)`

- PART_1 (test) => `A>0`
- PART_2 (if true) => `B`
- PART_3 (if false) => `(C>14 ? A*14 : -4)`

#### Case IV

Expression: `A>0 ? (A>0 ? 2-B : C) : (C>14 ? A*14 : -4)`

- PART_1 (test) => `A>0`
- PART_2 (if true) => `(A>0 ? 2-B : C)`
- PART_3 (if false) => `(C>14 ? A*14 : -4)`

### What I have done

In Notepad++ I have made the following REGEX to extract the three parts

**PART_1 (test)**

```
.*?\?
```

**PART_2 (if true)**

```
\?.*?:
```

**PART_3 (if false)**

```
:.*
```

without flag the *". matches newline"* option.

The main problem is that they match (of course) everything and not only the most external expressions so I can't use them with nested formulas.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In general, you need an expression parser like ANTLR here; regex by itself does not handle nested content well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Balanced Parentheses

The basic problem comes down to "balanced parentheses", which can be matched with

```
\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)
```

See here:

[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

### 3 Capture Groups

This expression captures an whole expression into the 3 capture groups

```
^((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^?\(])+?)\s*\?\s*((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^:\(\s])+?)\s*:\s*((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^\$\s])+)$
```

Yes, it can be made simpler, but we use this to separate the components into the 3 expressions for the 3 components

### "`condition`" (part 1)

```
^(?:(?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^?\(])+?)(?=\s*\?)
```

Assumes starts at the beginning of a line.
`(?=\s*\?)` is a positive-lookahead.

### "`value_if_true`" (part 2)

```
^((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^?\(])+?)\s*\?\s*\K((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^:\(\s])+?)(?=\s*:)
```

Basically, this one is made up from the "condition" regex then a `\K` which throws it away (so it's not captured) and then what we want to match followed by a lookahead.
We use the `\K` here because the regex engine (boost) Notepad++ I don't think supports infinite repetition in "positive-lookbehind".

### "`value_if_false`" (part 3)

```
:\s*\K((?:\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|[^\$\s])+)$
```

Again using `\K` here to throw that bit away.